# How to get rid of cellulite?

Tags: workout

What types of workouts or other things need to be done in order get rid of cellulite?

Answer (score 2):

If you have cellulite, it's going to be the last place your body loses fat because it's the hardest to access for energy.  You have to lose cellulite through diet and exercise just like any other type of fat.

Try taking Yohimbine HCl to help mobilize the fat.  It seems to redistribute the fat and you should lose weight more evenly when taking it.

Even when I am getting ready for a bodybuilding contest, the cellulite on my butt sticks around until only a few weeks out.  I can be ripped everywhere else, and still have a little cellulite texture on my butt.  To some degree it's genetic, and there's not a whole lot you can do about it

Answer (score 2):

Massaging the targeted area can also help reduce cellulite. For example, when showering, scrub and massage the affected area for several minutes a few times a week. This helps. Some cellulite treatments do actually work - St. Ives makes a couple of good brands of cellulite creams. The other thing that helps is mosturizing the areas - when the outer skin texture is thin, the cellulite shows more. Which is why we see more cellulite as we get older.

Comment: http://www.stives.com/Hand-(and)-Body-Lotion/Flawless-Beauty/Cellulite-Shield-Gel-Cr%C3%A8me/  

and this one: http://www.stives.com/Hand-(and)-Body-Lotion/Flawless-Beauty/Cellulite-Shield-Lotion/

Answer (score 2):

[VelaShape](http://www.velashape.com/how-velashape-works) is a new treatment that is out that is supposed to contour the body and reduce cellulite. There are also creams that can help reduce the appearance for short periods of time.

Combining cardio and toning exercises when working out will also help to create a leaner look.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to workout in a way so that you do many reps with relatively low weight. That way, you will start losing weight and getting into a shape. Were you to workout with high weights and few reps, you'd start gaining weight. Other than that, there isn't any *treatment* for cellulite.

Do some cycling and running and when in the gym, use low weights and go for 5 series of 30 reps, that should be enough to start losing weight where it isn't welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't "target" fat loss. You'll see a lot of people doing sit-ups to try and burn the belly fat but it just doesn't work. You need to get your body to access that fat. My suggestion is to do morning cardio BEFORE you eat. This is known as "fasted" cardio. What kind of cardio? My favorite is high-volume low impact, ie WALKING. You won't lose muscle doing this but your body will be more likely to access those fat stores. Good luck!